# Cannot read property of null error ONSEN Ui

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

I'm making a code that has a line of JavaScript which changes the text of the

element in the HTML code.

```js
    var card = document.getElementById("greeting");
    card.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<template id="home.html">

        <ons-page>
            <ons-fab position="bottom right" onclick="fn.load('item.html')">
                <ons-icon icon="md-plus"></ons-icon>
            </ons-fab>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left">
                    <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
                        <ons-icon icon="md-menu"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
                <div class="center">
                    Upcoming
                </div>
            </ons-toolbar>
            <ons-card onclick="fn.load('item.html')" id="greeting">
                <div class="title">No assignments!</div>
                <div class="content">Looks like you have no upcoming assignments! Press the "+" button to add a new assignment.</div>
            </ons-card>
        </ons-page>
```

Every time I execute the code, it always gives the the error: main.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you verify if the ID `greeting` is present in the DOM as well? If yes, when is your JS code getting executed?

Comment: Either don't put it in your `<head/>` elements or load it after the document is ready: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { // your code });`. Currently you're trying to select an element that does not exist yet because it's not loaded yet.